# XMLReader против feed Яндекс Фотки

Tags: xml

всем привет
нужны подсказки по обработке фида Яндекс Фоток
например, есть такой узел

```
<entry>
  <id>urn:yandex:fotki:автор:photo:700417</id>
  <author>
    <name>styleroom</name>
    <f:uid>13223519</f:uid>
  </author>
  <title>Название</title>
  <summary>описание</summary>
  <link href="http://path_to/photo/700417/" rel="self" />
  <link href="http://path_to/photo/700417/" rel="edit" />
  <link href="http://path_to/view/700417/" rel="alternate" />
  <link href="http://path_to_orig" rel="edit-media" />
  <link href="http://path_to/album/156904/" rel="album" />
  <published>2016-05-27T05:45:11Z</published>
  <app:edited>2016-05-28T18:49:35Z</app:edited>
  <updated>2016-05-28T18:49:35Z</updated>
  <f:access value="public" />
  <f:xxx value="false" />
  <f:hide_original value="false" />
  <f:disable_comments value="false" />
  <f:img height="75" href="http://path_to_XXS" size="XXS" width="75" />
  <f:img height="800" href="http://path_to_XL" size="XL" width="538" />
  <f:img height="300" href="http://path_to_M" size="M" width="202" />
  <f:img height="500" href="http://path_to_L" size="L" width="336" />
  <f:img height="50" href="http://path_to_XXXS" size="XXXS" width="50" />
  <f:img height="150" href="http://path_to_S" size="S" width="101" />
  <f:img height="100" href="http://path_to_XS" size="XS" width="67" />
  <f:img bytesize="149433" height="960" href="http://path_to_orig" size="orig" width="646" />
  <f:img height="960" href="http://path_to_XXL" size="XXL" width="646" />
  <category scheme="http://path_to/tags/" term="бабушка" />
  <category scheme="http://path_to/tags/" term="внучка" />
  <category scheme="http://path_to/tags/" term="грабли" />
  <content src="http://path_to_orig" type="image/*" />
</entry>
```

как правильно получить доступ к атрибутам узла и содержанию узла?
и как быть с узлом типа f:img?

Comment: Укажите язык, и может желаемую технологию. Можно отморозится и получить через regexp. Можно xsd запрос. На с# одно, на js другое. Приведите может фрагмент кода, где вы данные получили в некую переменную.

Comment: Еще можно получить с помощью сериализации. Есть как минимум 10 способов получить правильный ответ, если не намного больше.

Comment: @nick_n_a язык = php и насколько я понимаю в ридере идет перебор всех узлов по очереди без учета вложенности друг в друга

Comment: в с# тоже есть XmlReader, не XMLReader правда, но я вначале подумал что это с#, всёравно вопрос должен быть однозначный.